# Did the "Gift This App" option go away?

Tags: itunes-store, gift

I regularly gift apps to friends, but now I can't find the Gift button anywhere: Not in the sharing menu of the iPad's app store where it used to be, not under the disclosure arrow on the iTunes store under OSX. Did Apple deactivate the ability to gift apps?

Edited to add: No really, the menu options just don't seem to be there anymore. This is what it looks like when in the Mac version of the iTunes store:
[image]

And this is what I see in the iPad version of the app store:
[image]

Either way, the gift option isn't where it used to be.

Answer (score 5):

It's there for me both in iTunes and the iOS App Store (on an iPhone, don't have my iPad handy to test). That's in the Canadian store, FWIW. Things can and do vary by country, and for that matter by what CDN node you're connected to, so it may be different for others. Best advice is to wait it out and try again in a little while, in case there was a glitch somewhere along the line.

[image: gift this app example screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I first noticed this last night, when I was trying to send a birthday girl her present. The gift option is still missing for me today. I'm in the US.

Comment: On my iPhone, using the US store, it's still there. I'll annotate this answer with a screen capture that shows how to get to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the app I'm trying to gift this time is iPad only. It doesn't even show up when looking from an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like gifting an app only works for apps you haven't purchased yet. Comparing your screenshot with robmathers', yours has the **Open** button and his has the **Buy** button.